# What should we do with questions that could also be answered well by other sites?

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21086/xbox-360-slim-power-supply-unit-issue) is the one that I had in mind. It seems to me that it's similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12276/how-could-i-know-what-caused-the-yellow-light-of-death), basically a version of "Something bad happened to my X system ... what happened/how can I fix it?"

Both questions seem to me to fit on this site well, but the first question also seems like it could be easily answered by someone from electronics.SE. Is there some way to attract attention from Electronics people so someone can provide a technically accurate answer (based on the OP's description) while also leaving the question here, or is it better to migrate (or flag to migrate) the question because it could be better answered somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first - migration is for when a question does not belong on the current site, much more before it is for anything that *might* fare better on a different site. So unless the question is determined to be out of our scope (such as by not really being a gaming-specific question, our primary need to ever migrate to SU), migration is not really the go-to option.

**One simple thing to do is just check out [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com)**. Much like we have our own chat rooms, every other site on the network has at least one chatroom. And it's an easy way to grab people from that site and ask, "Hey, do you guys know anything about this?". A good advantage of this is that it prevents unnecessary clutter of the other sites when it may not even be addressed by them.

We even have success stories of things. [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/steam-on-ubuntu) was addressed by grabbing some AskUbuntu users, who had addressed a similar question back on their own site.

For questions that don't belong on our site, the chat is also a great way to *see if it's appropriate on the target site*. We've coordinated with both Super User and Game Development on multiple occasions when it has come to sketchy migrations, and [we even did a cute little question trade with Game Dev last month](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/705218#705218).

Comment: Thanks, Grace, this is what I would do if a similar question came up. Given the details the OP added to the question I linked, I don't think there's much of a question any more about what happened.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

Electronics.SE is ***not for consumer electronics***.  It is for electronics **design** questions.

Such suggestions reinforce how the willy-nilly movement of questions between sites creates  bad-blood between the different communities.  Movement should not be done at the whim of users or mods of the "donor" site alone, but by someone who has a good deal of experience on the "recipient" site.  Obviously, for the sake of user tools this is somewhat backwards, as you need sufficient rep on the donor site, but it doesn't care at all what your rep is on the recipient site.

In any case, if you strongly believe it should be moved, flag it and mods can do it.  But please, *please*, try to make sure it belongs there first, by yourself.  Never trust a mod<sup>TM</sup> to do so themselves.

Comment: I think this is a more general question, but Yes, it is good to share that we do not do consumer electronics.

Comment: See? This is an example of good communication. It's someone familiar with the target site telling us what would have been a horrible migration, *before* we clutter their site unnecessarily. That said, I think this probably would've been better as a comment.

Comment: As far as out-going mod migrations have gone, we've only had one incident, which did skip over checking with the target site first. Since we moderators actually can speak with the other moderators more directly and easily, sometimes it may be wiser to flag for us first, as we'll be able to check with the moderators of the target site for applicability.

Comment: Nick, thanks, the perspective on what works at electronics.SE is helpful to know. What I am hoping to find out are ways to get attention from other SE sites for questions that may require knowledge outside of what gaming.SE people may have.